# Update an array of hashes with records from the database adding a new field into each existing hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, activerecord, hash

I have an array called `records` with thousand of hashes (see the first array showed below). Every hash contains currently two fields `id` and `parent_id`. I want to add a new field called `updated_at` which is stored in the database (see the second array below).

```
records = [{"id"=>3, "parent_id"=>2}, 
           {"id"=>4, "parent_id"=>2}]

records = [{"id"=>3, "parent_id"=>2, "updated_at"=>"2014-03-21 20:44:35 UTC"}, 
           {"id"=>4, "parent_id"=>2, "updated_at"=>"2014-03-21 20:44:34 UTC"}]
```

My first approach is the following one, but it executes a query to the database for every hash, so if I have 1K hashes in the array, it is going to execute 1K queries, which I think is not very good from the performance point of view.

```
records.each do |record|
  record['updated_at'] = Record.find(record['id']).updated_at.utc.to_s
end
```

Can you suggest me a better solution?

Comment: Good question to follow *bookmarked* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?  Bulk up the queries by aggregating the ids a slice at a time.  Adjust `each_slice` amount to something that performs well...

```
records.each_slice(250) do |records|
  ids = records.map { |r| r['id'] }
  results = Record.select([:id, :updated_at]).find(ids)
  records.each do |rec|
    result = results.find { |res| res.id == rec.id }
    rec['updated_at'] = result.updated_at.utc.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Splitting an 'n+1 queries' problem into chunks is still an 'n+1 queries' problem.

Comment: But this 'n+1' queries is could be much better than doing 1 query and then performing a Ruby `.find` in a long list (with 1K items or more). I say that because I already tried that with 1 query and then I moved the performance issue from MySQL to Ruby and it was even slower than doing 1K queries. So something mixed could work.

Comment: Agreed.  You could also limit what is selected by `.select([:id, :updated_at])`.  Just added that to my answer.  If `Record` is huge, it may squeak out some more speed.

Comment: Thanks @Nick for you answer, it makes sense. Good correction replacing the `.select .. fist` by `.find`. I also think that you can retrieve less fields from your select, but not the whole record model (you just realised before I wrote that, thanks!). I hope to see more approaches.

Comment: Seemed like a fun exercise for a Friday afternoon. :)

Comment: Yes :) I am thinking about how to remove the `.find` - it is very expensive. Would be reliable to have both ordered so we can access by index instead of use `find`? Umm...

Comment: Thanks @NickVeys, your solution is quite good, specially with slice 50, as I said in my answer/comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
plucked_records = Record.pluck(:id, :updated_at).find(records.map { |a| a.fetch("id") })

records.map! do |record|
  plucked_records.each do |plucked_record|
    record["updated_at"] = plucked_record.last.utc.to_s if plucked_record.first == record["id"]
  end
  record
end
```

May be someone can improvise it better. :)

Comment: Thanks @Kirti, I will try it soon. I will use `select` instead of `pluck` since I am on Rails 3 and pluck does not accept more than one argument in this version. But leave as it is because I did not mention the Rails version and its better than the `select` for this case.

Comment: No Problem. I thought you were on Rails 4. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of benchmarks and trying different algorithms I have come up with a solution
that performs very fast and seems it is the most efficient one for now.

The idea is to convert the resulted array of db records into an hash, so
finding items into the hash is much faster than doing it into an array.

The time of the results came from benchmarks ran using an array of about 4.5K hashes.

```
# My last approach
# Converting the returning records Array into a Hash (thus faster searchs)
# Benchmarks average results: 0.5 seconds
ids = records.map { |rec| rec['id'] }
db_records = Record.select([:id, :updated_at]).find(ids)
hash_records = Hash[db_records.map { |r| [r.id, r.updated_at.utc.to_s] }]
records.each do |rec|
  rec["updated_at"] = hash_records[rec["id"]]
end

# Original approach
# Doing a SQL query for each pair (4.5K queries against MySQL)
# Benchmarks average results: ~10 seconds
records.each do |rec|
  db_rec = Record.find(pair['id'])
  rec["updated_at"] = db_rec.updated_at.utc.to_s
end

# Kirti's approach (slightly improved). Thanks Kirti! 
# Unfortunaly searching into a lar
# Doing a single SQL query for all the pairs (then find in the array)
# Benchmarks average results: ~18 seconds
ids = records.map { |rec| rec['id'] }
db_records = Record.select([:id, :updated_at]).find(ids)
records.each do |rec|
  db_rec = db_records.find { |f| f.id == pair["id"] }
  rec["updated_at"] = db_rec.updated_at.utc.to_s
end  

# Nick's approach. Thanks Nick! very good solution.
# Mixed solution levering in SQL and Ruby using each_slice.
# Very interesting results:
# [slice, seconds]:
# 5000, 18.0 
# 1000, 4.3
#  500, 2.6
#  250, 1.5
#  100, 1.0
#   50, 0.9 <- :)
#   25, 1.0
#   10, 1.8
#    5, 2.3
#    1, 10.0
# Optimal slice value is 50 elements! (for this scenario)
# An scenario with a much costly SQL query might require a higher slice number
slice = 50
records.each_slice(slice) do |recs|
  ids = recs.map { |pair| pair['id'] }
  db_records = Record.select([:id, :updated_at]).find(ids)
  recs.each do |rec|
    db_rec = db_records.find { |f| f.id == rec["id"] }
    rec["updated_at"] = db_rec.updated_at.utc.to_s
  end
end
```