# LINQ to Objects Performance - Huge dataset for long running process

Tags: c#, linq

I have a detail list (200,000 records) which was pulled from database and I need to find the locations for each detail and below is the code which is looping through the detail list and assigning location to the list. This loop is taking more than 15 minutes to execute but if don’t populate the Locations property then it takes less than a minute.

How can I optimize this code?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Details> databaseDetailList = GetDetailsFromdatabase();
        List<Location1> databaseLocation1List = GetLocations1Fromdatabase();
        List<Location2> databaseLocation2List = GetLocations2Fromdatabase();

        List<Details> detailList = new List<Details>();
        foreach (var x in databaseDetailList)
        {
            detailList.Add(new Details
            {
                DetailId = x.DetailId,
                Code = x.Code,
                //If I comment out the Locations then it works faster
                Locations = new LocationIfo {
                    Locations1 = databaseLocation1List
                                .Where(l=>l.DetailId == x.DetailId && l.Code == x.Code).ToList(),
                    Locations2 = databaseLocation2List
                                .Where(l => l.DetailId == x.DetailId && l.Code == x.Code).ToList()
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static List<Details> GetDetailsFromdatabase()
    {
        //This returns 200,000 records from database
        return new List<Details>();
    }

    private static List<Location1> GetLocations1Fromdatabase()
    {
        //This returns 100,000 records from database
        return new List<Location1>();
    }

    private static List<Location2> GetLocations2Fromdatabase()
    {
        //This returns 100,000 records from database
        return new List<Location2>();
    }
}

public class Details
{
    public string DetailId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public LocationIfo Locations { get; set; }
}

public class LocationIfo
{
    public List<Location1> Locations1 { get; set; }
    public List<Location2> Locations2 { get; set; }
}

public class Location1
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string DetailId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Location2
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string DetailId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is `Location1` exactly the same as `Location2`? Can you use LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Comment: This is a sample code. I have 2 sets objects which have many similar properties. for simplicity I kept the same properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing conceptually here is a `Join`.  Using the proper operations will ensure that it executes much more effectively.  Ideally you would even be doing the `Join` on the database side of things, rather than after pulling all of the data down into lists, but even if you do pull all of the data down, joining it in memory using `Join` will be *much* more efficient.

```
var query = from detail in databaseDetailList
            join location1 in databaseLocation1List
            on new { detail.DetailId, detail.Code }
            equals new { location1.DetailId, location1.Code }
            into locations1
            join location2 in databaseLocation2List
            on new { detail.DetailId, detail.Code }
            equals new { location2.DetailId, location2.Code }
            into locations2
            select new Details
            {
                Code = detail.Code,
                DetailId = detail.DetailId,
                Locations = new LocationIfo
                {
                    Locations1 = locations1.ToList(),
                    Locations2 = locations2.ToList(),
                }
            };
```

Comment: But the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) would be 2,000,000,000,000,000 returning all joined rows.  This is still the best idea, but making three calls returning each table (but joined) would be ideal.

Comment: I know that it is a join operation and I need to populate the detailList object. GetDetailsFromdatabase(), GetLocations1Fromdatabase(), GetLocations2Fromdatabase() are all service calls. can you please provide some sample code about what you are thinking. I am not getting your point.

Comment: @Servy, Thanks for the sample code. I tested it and this works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky - but you could use lookups:

If it's the look-up portion of your code that is taking the longest - and you can't change the database code, as suggested with a Join - you could consider indexing your `Location` return-types in an in-memory Lookup.

Build a Lookup key, that's a combination of your two values - this will need to be specifically unique, dependent on your requirements.

```
DetailId-Code - "123123-343"


private static ILookup<int, Location1> GetLocations1Fromdatabase()
{
    //This returns 100,000 records from database
    return new List<Location2>()
        .ToLookup(l => l.DetailId + "-" + l.Code);
}
```

Then:

```
Locations1 = databaseLocation1List[l.DetailId + "-" + l.Code].ToList()
```

Comment: Using a lookup is not hacky at all.  It is absolutely the correct solution to the problem.  Concatting the value of two strings to create a key is extremely hacky, error prone, and should not be done.  You should create (or use an existing) composite type with meaningful implementations of equality and hash code generation.

Comment: Why not use an anonymous object rather than a string concatenation there? Would save having to worry about using "-" as magic characters, etc. also I think there is an overload of ToLookup that makes the `l=>l` parameter unnecessary.

Comment: @Chris There's already [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22667590/1159478) (posted before this answer) that does just that.

Comment: @Servy: I was meaning one that uses lookups and anonymous objects. Your answer is good but the lookup one keeps more of the spirit of the original code (for better or for worse). And though I hadn't seen your comment at the time I definitely wouldn't bother creating a composite type with your own equality and hashcode when anonymous types work.

Comment: Ahh - the issue here is that you can't return an anonymous object as a key for a lookup, in the signature of a function - so, you'll need some kind of pre-defined key.

Comment: @Chris You need to use a composite object.  Whether you create one or use an existing one are both valid options; in this case an anonymous object is capable of solving the problem, so that *is* easier, which is why I did it myself.

Comment: @DaveBish The lookup, or the anonymous objects, don't need to leave the scope of that one method block; the lookup is just used to generate the populated sequence of `Detail` objects, so no (new) named type is needed.

Comment: @Servy - I'm not sure I know what you mean - Please feel free to edit my answer with your suggestion - I may learn something :)

Comment: @DaveBish: Oops, I hadn't noticed that your code was in a separate method so as you say anonymous types won't work. I'd just homed in on the `.ToLookup` call that I assumed would be in the main method of the above example.

Comment: Ahh, right - you could just move the lookup generation outside, gotcha

Answer (score 0):

This is [a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569662/update-an-array-of-hashes-with-records-from-the-database-adding-a-new-field-into) I faced a couple of days ago (in Ruby). 
Finally the best solution I found was to convert the List(or Array) into a Dictionary(or Hash)

Create a Dictionary with your searching fields concatenated as a key and your list item as as value:

```
var dict1 = databaseLocation1List.ToDictionary(x => x.DetailId.ToString() + x.Code.ToString(), x);
```

And then the search in the Dictionary by key will be very fast:

```
Locations1 = dict1[x.DetailId.ToString() + x.Code.ToString()].ToList()
```

Comment: The reason I suggested a Lookup, as in my answer - is that it appears there are multiple values for each Id-combo, hence the .ToList()

Comment: Using a lookup is not hacky at all.  It is absolutely the correct solution to the problem.  Concatting the value of two strings to create a key is extremely hacky, error prone, and should not be done.  You should create (or use an existing) composite type with meaningful implementations of equality and hash code generation.